# dark mode working! but when opening web page, it is not default mode

Tags: javascript

Dark mode working fine. but only the thing is, whenever I open the web page, always the dark mode is on at the beginning. I want it to be off at first and then turn on by switch. code is like this:

```
     let button = document.querySelector('.btn');
     let balls = document.querySelector('.btn-ball');

     button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
       if (balls.classList.contains('ball')){    
         balls.classList.remove('ball');
         document.body.classList.remove('all');
       } else {
         balls.classList.add('ball');
         document.body.classList.add('all');
       }
     })
```

```
html is like this:

          <div class="btn">
            <div class="btn-ball"></div>
         </div>
```

CSS code is this:

```
     .btn {
        width: 40px;
        height: 70px;
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 22px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 10px;
        left:10px;
        cursor: pointer;
     }
     .btn:hover {
          box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px lightcoral;
     }
     .btn .btn-ball {
          width:30px;
          height: 30px;
          background-color: black;
          margin: 5px auto;
          border-radius: 50%;
          transition: transform .3s ease-out;
     }
     .btn .ball {
          transform: translateY(30px)
     }
     .all {
       background-color: black;
       color: white;
     }
```

Comment: Can you post your css and html so we can understand what your JavaScript is doing?

Comment: oh sorry. I just repost all of them. thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exciting, I just worked through something similar! In my styles, a set of CSS variables are defaulted to light values. I use a media query and `:not()` selector combination to apply dark styles

```css
/** default light **/
:root {
  --color-surface: #fff;
}

/** override dark **/
:root.dark {
  --color-surface: #121212;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root:not(.light) {
    --color-surface: #121212;
  }
```

I have a radio group where the input value doubles as the class name. It's a pretty simple example, it could be rethought to work with a button, checkbox, or other control element.

```js
  const lightInput = document.getElementById('light');
  const darkInput = document.getElementById('dark');

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('light', 'dark'); // reset
    document.documentElement.classList.add(event.target.value);
  }

  // handle input events
  lightInput.addEventListener('input', handleInput);
  darkInput.addEventListener('input', handleInput);
```

```html
  <nav>
    <fieldset>
      Theme
      <label><input id="light" type="radio" name="theme" value="light"> light</label>
      <label><input id="dark" type="radio" name="theme" value="dark"> dark</label>
    </fieldset> 
  </nav>
```

I'll point out that I'm setting the class on the `<html>` element, not sure if it's recommended.

> I want [dark mode] to be off at first and then turn on by switch

I'll point out another difference here where I wanted to use a media query for the preferred color scheme first and offer a manual override control as secondary. If you need more details on that let me know, but I hope the explanation above helps.

Comment: wow thank you. to be honest, as I am new, that is whole another level.. I only studied basic JS and today I made dark mode and dropdown menu first time :)  I will study what you said and figure it out. thank you very much!!

Comment: Truly glad to help! It's been a fun topic and the new things I'm learning have been a blast to play with: CSS variables, CSS media query `prefers-color-theme`, [using media query list with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries). Thanks for asking your question, happy hacking!

Comment: Hi! today I fixed it!!^^ so happy, but I tried it by myself so it is different than what you taught me.  I just used window.addEventListener('load',function(){.      before function. and my background become default when it starts!!